# disable past time if choose current date on pickatime

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

i want to disbale past time in pickatime function when current date seletect in pickadate field.

```
var curr_date = new Date();
 $('#datepicker').pickadate({
         format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
          min: curr_date
 });
```

here is pick a time function.

```
$('#timepicker').pickatime({
            format:'h:i A',
            interval: 15, // 15 minutes
            //minTime: getCurrentTime(new Date())
        });
```

i tried many ways but didtn't work. so help me on this thanks.

Comment: why php is tagged?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:
In html i have 2 input fields for date and time:
In

```js
var min_date = new Date();
    $('#input_time').pickatime({
        format:'h:i A',
        interval: 15    
        
    });
    var picker = $('#input_time').pickatime().pickatime('picker');
    $('#input_date').pickadate({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
             min: min_date,
             onSet: function(context) {
                var curr_date = new Date();
                var curr_hour = curr_date.getHours();
                var curr_min = curr_date.getMinutes();
                curr_min= (Math.round(curr_min/15) * 15) % 60;
                 var selectedDate=new Date(context.select);
                 if(curr_date.getDate() == selectedDate.getDate()){
                    picker.set('disable', [{ from: [0,0], to: [curr_hour,curr_min] }]);  
                 }
                 else{
                    picker.set('enable',  true)
                 }
                
            }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input-field-animated" type="text" id="input_date" />
<input class="input-field-animated" type="text" id="input_time" />
```

In javascript I check if date is today(i am not allowing past date to be entered), past time should be disabled, but if any other future date is selected, all time is enabled.

*** this snippet will not run as pickadate library is not included***